# IBM ODM - How to do rule logging in 8.12 version

Tags: ibm-odm

I'm new to ODM 8.12, just doing some discovery for migrating from ODM 8.9.2 to 8.12. Old versions of ODM had IlrLogHandler with various methods for rule execution start , rule execution end.Do we have similar kind of api's available to check the execution start and end at each rule level.
Thanks

IlrLogHandler is deprecated, RuleEngineObserver has ruleExecutionStarted and ruleExecutionEnded methods, but need help on whether I can use the same in ODM 8.12 and if yes, how to initialize the custom observer.

Answer (score 0):

jain

you can find a proper example here of exactly what you're searching for :

- using an ODM observer
- adding it to the engine for runtime info
- you can add log information in the Observer methods to see your rule logging

https://github.com/DecisionsDev/decision-engine-observer-sample

Best
Emmanuel